# How can I decide on a size of my Android drawables?

Tags: android, dpi, multiple-sizes

I understand how big should my drawable be when it's displayed in a certain size, e.g. 24dp, 48dp etc. But what if the size was dynamic, for example, it takes up the half of the screen? In that case, there isn't a predetermined size, but it is rather calculated on-spot, and is different on different devices. So in which sizes should my drawables be, so that they're neither too big (it would cause performance issues), nor too small (it would be blurry)?